# How many bags can be made out of 4 kinds of balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> We have balls in a bin, $30$ balls of type $a$, $30$ balls of type $b$, $30$ balls of type $c$, $30$ balls of type $d$. We take out one ball per minute in random and move it to a bag.
>
> 1. How many bags can be made after one hour?
> 2. What is the shortest amount of time that we will have at least 15 balls of the same kind for certain.

1. We need to solve $\binom{30} k\binom{30} l \binom{30} m \binom{30} n$ such that $k+l+m+n=60$ and $k,l,m,n$ are non negative integers. This is a non distinct balls into bins problem, so the solution is: $\binom {60+4-1}{4-1}$. Now I'm not sure, is this enough or we need to multiply it by: $\binom{30} k\binom{30} l \binom{30} m \binom{30} n$ ?
2. The answer is the 57th minute, because we can have 14 balls of each kind up to the 56th minute, and then we'll have to take the 15th ball out of one of them.

Also, is it possible to use inclusion exclusion here?

Comment: We can assume the bag can hold 60 balls. It's like asking how many possibilities there are to create a set of balls from those we took out. No you can't be certain that you took 15 balls of the same type after 15 minutes.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't the number of bags the same as the number of solutions to $a+b+c+d=60$ with $a,b,c,d \leq 30$? Using `FrobeniusSolve[]` on Mathematica with the very equation you gave in the post yields $19871$.

Comment: I've also obtained the same number as the coefficient of $x^{60}$ in the expansion of the generating function $(\sum_{x=0}^{30})^4$.

Comment: @Voyska yeah I just wanted to make sure. What is the generating function btw?

Comment: This is the generating function $(\sum_{n=0}^{30} x^n)^4$. I made a silly mistake in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. About the first part, yes $C(63,3)$ is the answer and there is no need to multiply it.
2. And for the second part, I think it is more proper to use Pigeonhole principle.
    If $m$ be our desired number of balls , $m$ holds in $\lceil m/4 \rceil=15$ according to the principle.
   since $m$ must be minimum, it would equals to $57$